# How to get first value in a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with single column and that column has multiple values in there. I want to get first value. Below is the example of dataframe with column name= A.
I want to get value abc, XYZ in my output.
how can I do that?

```
    A
abc, 123, 888
XYZ, 789, 999
```

Comment: Do you mean the column contains a list of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column A contains strings, use:

```
df['A'].str.split(', ').str[0]
```

Output (Series):

```
0    abc
1    XYZ
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
[e.split(', ')[0] for e in df['A']]
```

Output (list): `['abc', 'XYZ']`

---

If you have lists:

```
df['A'].str[0]
```

Or:

```
[e[0] for e in df['A']]
```